# Determine marginal revenue given demand curve and marginal cost

Tags: demand, marginal, cost-functions

a)Determine marginal revenue curve if firm can only charge 1 price,List demand curve,marginal revenue curve,,marginal cost,average total cost equations.

b)What is optimal price and quantity?

c)If firm fixed cost are 16 dollars, what are the profits?

P=20-q

MC=12

Attempt:

I tried

mc=c/p

12*20-q=x

to find P*X=MR

b)

12=240-12q

q=-228/12

c)

MC=6

6=240-12q/20-q

q=24

The numerical answer is wrong so what mistake did I make? What's the correct equation to solve for test equation?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the firm is a monopolist.

We know the inverse demand function, the fixed costs and the marginal costs:

- $P(q) = 20 - q$
- $MC(q) = 12$
- $F = 16$

As the marginal costs are constant, we can compute the total costs function as:

- $TC(q) = MC\cdot q + F = 12 q + 16$

The average total costs is obtained by dividing by $q$:

- $AC(q) = \frac{TC(q)}{q} = 12 + \frac{16}{q}$

The demand curve is obtained by inverting the inverse demand function:

- $q(P) = 20 - P$

Total revenue is obtained by multiplying together price and quantity:

- $R(q) = P(q)\cdot q = (20-q)\cdot q = 20 q - q^2$

Marginal revenue is obtained by taking the derivative of revenue with respect to $q$

- $MR(q) = \frac{\partial R(q)}{\partial q} = 20 - 2q$.

If the firm maximizes profits, then the marginal revenue equals the marginal costs so:

- $12 = 20 - 2q \to q = 4$

The optimal price can be found by substituting $q = 4$ into the inverse demand function:

- $P = 20 - 4 = 16$

Profits are determined as total revenue minus total costs:

- $\pi = R - TC = P\cdot q - TC = 16 \cdot 4 - (12 \cdot 4 + 16) = 0$